# Flashbuilder 4.5 Android Camera restarting my application

Tags: android, camera, adobe, flash-builder

I'm working with FlashBuilder 4.5 and trying to make an app for Android that uses the camera function.  It works fine on iOS, but in Android, I am able to take the picture using the android Camera UI, but anything I do after that (hit cancel, or Accept), it restarts my application.  I am taken to the splash screen and the app starts over.  I do not have any sort of Event.DEACTIVATE listeners going on.  I did, but I have them commented out.  I am able to click Home, to return to the "desktop" of the phone, and when I relaunch my app, it returns to where I left it.  The only problem is when I go out to the Camera from within my app, it causes my app to lose focus and forces a restart when I try and go back to it.  I have scoured google for someone else with this problem but no one else seems to have it.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

This problem was driving me crazy as well, but it can be solved by enabling session persistence on the main ViewNavigator or TabbedViewNavigator page.

See [Adobe Flex 4.6 * Enable persistence in a mobile application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSb0a29bf92525419c-54dd253312afbec3ecb-8000.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I have been experiencing this problem for several months, both through FlashBuilder 4.5 (with Flex 4.5 and 4.5.1 sdk's) and through pure Flash (using Flex 4.6 sdk).  I was hoping it was some sort of bug only in FB, but apparently not.

I notice that the problem is intermittent, but I can't predict when it will fail.  Sometimes it fails on taking a new picture (Camera) and sometimes it fails on retrieving images from the CameraRoll.  Any situation like this is obviously unacceptable, but I'm trying to figure out the situation in which it occurs.

Usually when I restart the phone, the problem will go away for some time.  That makes me think about some memory thing, but I haven't confirmed anything.

I made a very simple test case in which it fails (just takes a picture), when I see it failing in my main app. I submitted it to Adobe as a bug (#3099508), but I don't know if they can reproduce it reliably.

Have you done any memory profiling to see if there is something up when the problem occurs?  My only "hail Mary" option I can think of is to use a Native Extension for the camera, but I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: I just saw this comment in the CameraUI docs (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/CameraUI.html): "In addition, the AIR application that launches the camera loses focus. If the device runs low on resources, the AIR application can be terminated by the operating system before the media capture is complete."  If this is what is happening (though I'm not at all certain it is), the question is whether we can detect this situation and warn the user or clean stuff up ourselves.

Comment: A little more digging and I found that the low resource thing has been an issue at least since AIR 2.5 (http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/868/cpsid_86822.html) : Android: CameraUI - Launching the camera user interface moves the AIR application to the background and makes it vulnerable to termination when Android runs low on resources. The same behavior is seen in native applications.