# Adobe Flex mobile selecting image from camera roll or taking picture restarts the application

Tags: apache-flex, upload, camera, adobe

I have a flex mobile application that I am working on that I am having issues with selecting an image from roll/taking a picture.  My application is not tabbed, however one part of it contains a Tabbed View Navigator with tabs across the bottom.  Within one of those tabs, I have the ability to upload an image to a webservice that I have created.  However, when I select an image or take the picture, it pops back out to the initial splash screen and the application restarts.  If I use the component standalone (outside of the tabbed view navigator) it selects the image and uploads without any problem.

```
<s:TabbedViewNavigator id="tvn" width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:ViewNavigator icon="@Embed('assets/icons/contact.png')"  label="contact" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="Concern.ContactInfo" firstViewData="{data}"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator icon="@Embed('assets/icons/notes.png')" label="details" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="Concern.Description"  firstViewData="{data}"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator icon="@Embed('assets/icons/updates.png')" label="updates" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="Concern.Updates"  firstViewData="{data}"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator icon="@Embed('assets/icons/upload.png')" label="uploads" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="Concern.Uploads" firstViewData="{data}"/>
</s:TabbedViewNavigator>
```

Concern.Uploads:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

private var urlRequest:URLRequest = new ULRequest("http://mywebservice.php");
            private var file:File;

```
        //take a new picture with the camera
        protected function uploadCamera_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (CameraUI.isSupported)
            {
                trace("camera is supported");
                var myCam:CameraUI = new CameraUI();
                myCam.launch(MediaType.IMAGE);
                myCam.addEventListener(MediaEvent.COMPLETE,selectCompleteHandler);
            }
            else
            {
                trace("camera not supported");
                statusText.text = "Camera not supported on this device.";
            }
        }

        //select a picture from the camera roll (gallery)
        protected function uploadGallery_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (CameraRoll.supportsBrowseForImage)
            {
                trace("camera roll is supported");
                var roll:CameraRoll = new CameraRoll();
                roll.browseForImage();
                roll.addEventListener(MediaEvent.SELECT,selectCompleteHandler);
            }
            else
            {
                trace("camera roll not supported");
                statusText.text = "Camera roll not supported on this device.";
            }
        }

        //when the selection is complete upload it
        protected function selectCompleteHandler(event:MediaEvent):void
        {
            trace("event.data.file.url; = "+event.data.file.url);
            takePhotoButton.enabled = galleryPhotoButton.enabled = false;
            file = event.data.file;
            file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,uploadCompleteHandler);
            file.addEventListener(Event.OPEN,openUploadHandler);
            urlRequest = new URLRequest("http://MyWebService.php?ID=" + data.ID.toString());
            statusText.text = "Uploading please wait...";
            file.upload(urlRequest);                
        }

        protected function uploadCompleteHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            trace("upload complete");
            takePhotoButton.enabled = galleryPhotoButton.enabled = true;
            statusText.text = "Photo Uploaded";
        }

        protected function openUploadHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            trace("uploading");
            statusText.text = "Uploading...";
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Image source="@Embed('assets/i/logo.jpg')" horizontalAlign="center" horizontalCenter="0" bottom="0"/>
<s:Label width="100%" id="res" textAlign="left"/>
<s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" verticalAlign="top" paddingLeft="15" paddingRight="15" horizontalAlign="center">
        <s:VGroup width="100%" paddingTop="15">
            <s:Label text="My Header" styleName="cityTitle" width="100%">
                <s:filters>
                    <s:DropShadowFilter color="#000000"/>
                </s:filters>
            </s:Label>
            <s:Label text="Portal" styleName="citySubtitle" width="100%">
                <s:filters>
                    <s:DropShadowFilter color="#000000"/>
                </s:filters>
            </s:Label>
        </s:VGroup>
        <s:VGroup horizontalAlign="center" gap="25" width="100%">
            <s:Button id="takePhotoButton" label="Take Photo" click="uploadCamera_clickHandler(event)" minHeight="50" width="50%"/>
            <s:Button id="galleryPhotoButton" label="From Gallery"
                      click="uploadGallery_clickHandler(event)" minHeight="50" width="50%"/>                
            <s:Label id="statusText" fontSize="24" text="" color="#FFFFFF"/>                
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Scroller>
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

JH

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten similar behavior and recently added my insights to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512165/flashbuilder-4-5-android-camera-restarting-my-application/9037019#9037019%29). I saw something in release notes for AIR 2.5 about the possibility of Android killing your process when the camera is low on resources.

I think it is a FOL for at least awhile, I filed a bug report (#3099508) with Adobe.  I have found if I turn off Data and GPS, so lower the resources being used currently, I have a greater chance of it working.  Very frustrating, but I haven't seen any workaround.  In my app, I am going to detect the situation by making a note (shared object) when I press the button before going to the camera, then clear it when it returns, but if the app starts with that note set, I will put up a dialog box advising to lower resources and this is an AIR bug.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that does sound like it could be the same issue.  Also, thanks for the idea on saving data to the phone before starting the camera, it is a pain, but I believe I can implement a workaround.